# trying to access rel attribute of <a> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, overlay

I am using an javascript overlay in my site for my subscription form. I have loaded the code for overlay from net. It is in javascript. Now the thing is to trigger the overlay function using a link i need put some value under `<a rel="">`.
more specifically, `<a href="subscribe.php" rel="gb_page_center[450, 450]">click</a>`

But i dont want to put a  tag instead i want to link to the subscription page using javascript function. Now my problem is how or where do i put the value under 'rel' attribute in my javascript to get the same result???

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: So you want to place the `gb_page...` into the `rel` attribute programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

Like this:
`<a href="#;" onclick="alert(this.rel);return false;" rel="bob">A</a>`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use plain JS without jQuery, try setAttribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute

Give your  tag an id attribute and then you can add:

document.getElementById("your_id").setAttribute("rel", "gb_page_center[450, 450]");

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, this can be accomplished quite cleanly by using the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$('a').attr('rel', 'gb_page_center[450, 450]');
```

Comment: He's asking about using javascript. jQuery is a framework with a footprint of ~34KB and only to do that is an overkill. :P